# Transfer Data between VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to transfer data from a Label (result of calculation) in VC1 to another label in VC2.
I got an error "Incompatible pointe types assigning to NSString *_Nullable from UILabel*" In the ViewController2.m <

ViewController.h:

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ResultVC1;
```

View Controller.m:

```
    - (IBAction)GoToVc2Button:(id)sender {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueToVc2" sender:self];
}
#pragma mark - Data Sending
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueToVC2"]) {
    ViewController2 *secondVC=(ViewController2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
secondVC.ResultFromVc1=self.lab;
}
}
```

ViewController2.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *labelVC2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ResultFromVc1;
```

ViewController2.m:

```
NSLog(@"Result From Vc1 is%@",self.ResultFromVc1);
_labelVC2.text=self.ResultFromVc1;
```

Comment: why you assign label ???? label.text returns String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code for the line causing the error. Read the error. It's pretty clear what the issue is. You are assigning a `UILabel` to an `NSString` property.

```
_labelVC2.text=self.ResultFromVc1;
```

should be:

```
_labelVC2.text=self.ResultFromVc1.text;
```

But why are you pass a `UILabel` to a `UILabel`? You should pass an `NSString` to an `NSString`. Then use the string to set the label's text.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set the view component (lab in viewController1) of one VC to the view component of another VC (labelVC2 of VC2). This is not the right way to do. If you just want to copy the result you can just pass the result string like :

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueToVC2"]) {
    ViewController2 *secondVC=(ViewController2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
secondVC.labelVC2.text =self.ResultVC1.text;
}
```

Comment: This won't work. `secondVC.labelVC2` is a `UILabel`. You can't assign an `NSString` to it.

Comment: At this point, as mentioned in my answer, there is no reason why `labelVC2` is a `UILabel`. It should just be an `NSString`.

Answer (score 1):

```
In VC2
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *strVal;

-(void) ViewDidLoad
{
labelVC2.text=strVal;
}
In VC1

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueToVC2"]) {
    ViewController2 *secondVC=(ViewController2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
secondVC.strVal=@"Hello";
}
}
```